How do I compare cruise fuel consumption with overall fuel consumption?
I've read, that the Otto Celera 500L consumes 7.8/100 L/Km of fuel, which is supposed to be very low. That plane seats 6 supposedly, so it's 1.3/100 L/(Passenger Km) So, I'm checking out the tabble in the Fuel Economy of Aircraft Wikipedia page - but there, the figures are for an entire flight - short haul, medium range, long haul etc. - but per flight.
How do I relate the cruise figures to the whole-flight figures? And - shouldn't fuel economy figures include a cruise component and a takeoff + landing component, separately?

This aircraft is basically vaporware at this point, so everything about its performance should be taken with a large grain of salt.  Also "should" data be broken down into whatever components, for a vaporware aircraft, is pretty well in the realm of opinions rather than hard facts.

@RalphJ: Yes, fixed. But the question is not really about the aircraft, more about comparing figures in principle, as the title suggests.

It's not totally clear what you are asking:  Where to get the data, how to separate cruise fuel burn from climb and descent, or how to "compare" them...  Which one is it, or are you asking for all three?  If you are looking for a specific model aircraft that information is typically in the performance charts in the Flight Manual.  So the short generic answer is to get into the performance charts...

@MichaelHall: The second and third items, I guess.


Shouldn't fuel economy figures include a cruise component and a takeoff + landing component, separately?

You are correct in presuming that whole-flight fuel consumption numbers are comprised of three main phases of flight:  Take-off/Climb fuel, Cruise fuel, and Descent/Landing fuel.  Fuel consumption on each segment is derived from performance charts in the aircraft flight manual, and then added together as total fuel burned.

If you have access to performance charts and are computing actual fuel burned for a specific leg you would already know it.
However, if all you have is a total and are asking whether Wikipedia (or any public source) "should" display each phase of flight separately I would suggest that while that might be your personal preference, it would probably be more information than most users care about.


How do I relate the cruise figures to the whole-flight figures?

You can't, at least not from the information provided in the link.  Once the fuel has been totaled you cannot work backwards without knowing at least two of the three subtotals.
(It would be like trying to determine whether 18 is the sum of 6, 6, & 6, or 7, 6, & 5.)
